# System.IndexOutOfRangeException con C# en una función

Tags: c#

En esta función por ejemplo, si recibe `(3-2)` debería devolver uno, sin embargo hay una excepción `IndexOutOfRangeException` en la línea `int firstNumber = Convert.ToInt32(ecu[1]);`

**La función completa:**

```
static int CalculateSimpleEquation(string ecu)
    {

        int firstNumber = Convert.ToInt32(ecu[1]);    ==> 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException
        int secondNumber = Convert.ToInt32(ecu[3]);
        char sign = ecu[2];
        if (sign == '*')
            return firstNumber * secondNumber;
        if (sign == '/')
            return firstNumber / secondNumber;
        if (sign == '+')
            return firstNumber + secondNumber;
        return firstNumber - secondNumber;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Tu problema es muy evidente, los lenguajes de programación modernos (salvo contados casos) comienzan a contar los índices de los array en `0`, no en `1`.

[Según la documentación de microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/):

> Las matrices se indexan con cero: una matriz con n elementos se indexa de 0 a n-1.

Por ende, en tu código, `ecu[1]` vale `-`, por lo que podras imaginarte, `ecu[3]` no existe, y esto produce la excepción que mencionas ([`IndexOutOfRangeException`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.indexoutofrangeexception.-ctor?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.IndexOutOfRangeException.%2523ctor);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8)).

Para que esto quede claro, asumiendo que le pases `"3-2"` de parámetro a tu función, la representación como array sería la siguiente.

[image: Imágen de la cadena]

Por lo que como puedes ver, el número `3` en realidad se encuentra en la posición `0`, no en la `1`

Y también podrás notar, que la posición `3`, simplemente no existe.

Para poder solucionar tu problema, deberás corregir los índices, teniendo en cuenta que un array es [base 0](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_(inform%C3%A1tica)).

Answer (score 1):

Te comento:

Si envías `string ecu = "3-2"`, el índice máximo al cual puedes acceder de `ecu` es el `2`.

3 = índice 0;

"-" = índice 1;

2 = índice 2;

por lo cual yo creo que tu error estaría en:

```
int secondNumber = Convert.ToInt32(ecu[3]);
```

recuerda que la cuenta de índices empieza desde el 0.
igual veo que mencionas que si recibe (3-2) debería devolver uno, eso no va a pasar, cuando accedes a los índices de un `string`, aún convirtiendo el valor a `int`, no te va a regresar el número natural, te va a devolver el valor ASCII del número, y por ejemplo el de 3 es 51. Saludos